# pstricks rput does not place stuff precisely

Tags: xetex, pdf, pstricks, dvipdfmx

### Description

I want to use `pstricks` to place some stuff in a large (almost [A0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_size)) `pspicture`. Any stuff I place in the picture with the `\rput` command, **is not placed precisely**. Why? The farther away from the grid origin I place it, the larger offset it gets. Here is a minimal working example.

### Minimal working example

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=2cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
% Draw a large picture (81x81 cm)
\begin{pspicture}(81,81)

% This "X" in the grid origin (0,0) is placed precisely (no error here)
\rput{0}(0,0){X}
% An "X" put to (80,80), however, is placed with a significant offset (ERROR)
\rput{0}(80,80){X}
% Drawing a line that far away, on the other hand, works precisely again (no error)
\psline(79,79)(80,80)

% commands which draw the grid and label it on all 4 sides
\psset{origin={0,0}}
\psgrid[gridcolor=red, subgriddiv=1, griddots=10, gridlabels=12pt](81,81)(0,0)
\psgrid[gridcolor=red, subgriddiv=0, griddots=10, gridlabels=12pt]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

### My configuration

I am using MiKTeX-XeTeX 2.9.4987 (0.9999.3) (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit), Windows 7.
XeTeX is Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)

In order to typeset a picture this large with `xelatex`, I had to use the workaround [Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967/heiko-oberdiek) suggested as a solution to [this problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157216/xetex-pstricks-larger-page-size-is-cropped-to-a4). It boils down to replacing the parameter `-dEPSCrop` with `-sPAPERSIZE=a0` in `dvipdfmx.cfg`.

### Error presentation

- X was specified to be placed by `\rput` at (80,80) but it is placed off grid by approx 3 millimeters.
- Error does not happen with `\psline` which is drawn precisely where I specified:

[image: X is placed off grid]

I tried `\rput(x,y){stuff}` where I gradually changed `x` and `y`. The error gets linearly bigger and bigger the farther from the grid's origin X is placed. Enabling the rulers in Acrobat Reader (used to view the resulting PDF) proved that the grid and the line are placed precisely. The X, however, is not.

### Expected result

At the grid's origin everything looks fine (X is placed precisely):
[image: X is placed precisely]

I'd expect the X be placed just like this at `(80, 80)`

Comment: I also cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: I use the following step: `latex filename.tex` and then `dvips -t unknown filename.dvi` and then `gswin64c -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dAutoRotatePages=/None -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o filename.pdf filename.ps`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
\rput(! \pstnodescale\space 80 80){X}% scales down from pt to bp
```

and it will be correct. It is a problem with the `xdvipdfmx` config file. Needs some more investigations. With the `dvips` driver it is ok.
You can also update your TeX distribution, then it is done by default.

[image]

If you do not have an up-to-date PSTricks then write also into the preamble `\SpecialCoor`

Comment: Thank you it works, I shall use this as a temporary workaround. Hopefully someone finds the real cause of this so people can fix this bug.

Comment: @Herbert This problem still seems to exist (I've encountered it in another context). Is it just a matter of changing `\pstnodescale` in `xdvipdfmx.cfg`?

Comment: I cannot see it. Give an example!

Comment: I've sent a message with an example to the PSTricks list.