# Aligning lines and crosses placed with `rput` (place an object at a desired point)

Tags: xetex, pstricks, pspicture, dvipdfmx

I would like to slightly modify this `ps`picture:

[image]

Each of the crosses (as well as the numbers, although that is not so important) should be centred at the centre of their each squares.
As you can see in the example below, I have tried both using `\rput`and `uput`, but neither seems to work. One provides correctly the x-coordinate, while the other gets correctly only the y-coordinate.

The `mwe` below uses the answer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194683/pstricks-rput-does-not-place-stuff-precisely) question. Although there is some imporvement, some crosses are still off:

[image]

How could I achieve the desire result?

Thank you in advance.

PS: Any modifications regarding the cells with the numbers is also very welcome.

Here is the `mwe`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\usepackage{pst-all}



\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-6,-6)(6,6)
%\psset{unit = 1}

\psaxes[linewidth=.4pt,linecolor=gray,showorigin=false,labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(-5,-5)(-5.5,-5.5)(5.5,5.5)[$u$,0][$v$,90]
\psaxes[linewidth=0pt,linecolor=gray,dx=2,Ox=0]{-}(-4,-5)(-4,-5)(4,-5)
\psaxes[linewidth=0pt,linecolor=gray,dy=2,Oy=0]{-}(-5,-4)(-5,-4)(-5,4)

   
%GRID
\psline{-}(-5,-5)(5,-5)
\psline{-}(-5,-3)(5,-3)
\psline{-}(-5,-1)(5,-1)
\psline{-}(-5,1)(5,1)
\psline{-}(-5,3)(5,3)
\psline{-}(-5,5)(5,5)
\psline{-}(-5,-5)(-5,5)
\psline{-}(-3,-5)(-3,5)
\psline{-}(-1,-5)(-1,5)
\psline{-}(1,-5)(1,5)
\psline{-}(3,-5)(3,5)
\psline{-}(5,-5)(5,5)

%LABELS
%zeroth row
\rput[B](-4,-4){$\substack{(0,0)\\ \! \\(4,2)}$}
\rput[B](-2,-4){$\substack{(1,0)\\ \! \\(3,2)}$}
\rput[B](0,-4){$\substack{(2,0)\\ \! \\(2,2)}$}
\rput[B](2,-4){$\bigtimes$}
\rput[B](4,-4){$\bigtimes$}
%first row
\rput[B](-4,-2){$\bigtimes$}
\rput[B](-2,-2){$\substack{(1,1)\\ \! \\(3,1)}$}
\rput[B](0,-2){$\substack{(2,1)\\ \! \\(2,1)}$}
\rput[B](2,-2){$\substack{(1,0)\\ \! \\(3,1)}$}
\rput[B](4,-2){$\bigtimes$}
%second row
\rput[B](-4,0){$\bigtimes$}
\uput[0](-4,0){$\bigtimes$}
\rput[B](-2,0){$\bigtimes$}
\rput[B](0,0){$\substack{(2,0)\\ \! \\(2,2)}$}
\rput[B](2,0){$\substack{(1,0)\\ \! \\(3,2)}$}
\rput[B]{0}(4,0){$\substack{(0,0)\\ \! \\(4,2)}$}
%third row
\rput[B](2,2){$\bigtimes$}
\rput[B](4,2){$\bigtimes$}
%fourth row
\rput[B](4,4){$\bigtimes$}


\psline{-}(-4,-2)(-4,0)
\psline{-}(-4,0)(-2,0)
\psline{-}(2,-4)(4,-4)
\psline{-}(4,-4)(4,-2)


\end{pspicture}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of  `\rput[B](-4,0){$\bigtimes$}` use

```
\psdot[dotstyle=x,dotscale=3](-4,0)
```

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought the code was `\rput(! \pstnodescale\space -4 0){$\bigtimes$}`. Anyway, your solution works perfectly. Thank you! (I can't upvote yet because of my low reputation.)