# can't draw a line far enough to the right in a pspicture in landscape

Tags: xetex, pstricks, landscape

I want to use `pspicture` in a landscape document, but I can't draw a line to the right hand side of the document with `\psframe`, while `\rput` works as expected. I've tried to create an MWE to demonstrate the behavior.

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\usepackage{scrlayer}
\usepackage[landscape]{pstricks}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(15,10)
    \psset{unit=1mm}
    \psgrid

    \rput[lt](200,20){Text}

    \psframe[fillstyle=solid,linecolor=black,fillcolor=black,linestyle=solid](0,60)(190,60)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid,linecolor=black,fillcolor=black,linestyle=solid](0,50)(180,50)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid,linecolor=black,fillcolor=black,linestyle=solid](0,40)(170,40)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid,linecolor=black,fillcolor=black,linestyle=solid](0,30)(160,30)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid,linecolor=black,fillcolor=black,linestyle=solid](0,20)(150,20)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid,linecolor=black,fillcolor=black,linestyle=solid](0,10)(140,10)
\end{pspicture}

paperwidth: \the\paperwidth

paperheight: \the\paperheight

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same behavior happens for `\psframe` and `\psline`.

I'm usind xelatex, as provided by texlive 2014.20141024-2 in debian GNU/Linux, to compile the whole thing.
This seams to be `xelatex` specific, since everything seams to be fine with `latex` -> `dvips` -> `ps2pdf`.

Comment: What happens if you increase the size of `pspicture` to `(20,10)`?

Comment: @Christoph no difference in the output, I could even put `0` or `500` as width an there is no difference.

Comment: Hm. With miktex everything is fine, but in texlive2014 the picture is gone.

Comment: Does it mean this is a bug of texlive? Where should I report it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is due to a too small postscript/ghostscript `DEFAULTPAPERSIZE`, which as well is applied in portrait mode, rather an rotated to landscape. This is also documented in “[XeTeX pstricks larger page size is cropped to A4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157216/xetex-pstricks-larger-page-size-is-cropped-to-a4)”

A workaround is to build the document e.g. with (resp. a large enough paper size)

```
 GS_OPTIONS=-sDEFAULTPAPERSIZE=a0 xelatex <your tex file>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no problem with `xelatex` and `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf`

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,0)(\textwidth,10)
\psframe*[linecolor=blue!30](0,0)(\textwidth,10)
\psline(\textwidth,10)
\end{pspicture}

paperwidth: \the\paperwidth

paperheight: \the\paperheight

\end{document}
```

Up-to-date TeXLive 2014

[image]