# XeLaTeX, Landscape Setting Papersize for PSTricks Graphic

Tags: xetex, pstricks, landscape

I found that my PSTricks Graphics only work in Landscape when I edit the `dvipdfmx.cfg` and add `-sPAPERSIZE=a0` to the line

```
%% Use MiKTeX Ghostscript:
D  "mgs.exe -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dEPSCrop -sPAPERSIZE=a0 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=%v -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode -sOutputFile=\"%o\" \"%i\" -c quit"
```

But at my WorkPC I don't have access to this `.cfg` file

Can I achieve the same, from out of TexWorks (I use Miktex 2.9) or out of the document somehow? I want a PDF Output.

I can't use other LaTeX editors, or other MikTeX versions.

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,9pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage[newdimens]{labels}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
landscape, 
margin=0mm
}

\newcommand{\sap}[2]{
\centering\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(7,4)\psbarcode[scaley=1.5]{#2}{includetext textsize=10 width=2.8}{code128}
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}

\LabelCols=2
\LabelRows=2
\LabelSetup
\begin{labels}
\sap{Gblalbla1}{209ss4}
\sap{GGblalbla1}{20ss9214}
\sap{Gblalbla}{2092ss141}
\sap{blablabal}{209ss214}%
\end{labels}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post a minimal (non-)working example?

Comment: @Bernard i added some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it myself.

You have to go to the CMD Shell and type

```
initexmf --edit-config-file dvipdfmx
```

this will create a config File in your Windows User Directory, which even in Workplaces usually is not write protected. In this file you can make any changes, and the original file will be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

No problem with up-to-date TL2015:

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[newdimens]{labels}
\LabelCols=2
\LabelRows=2
\LabelSetup
\usepackage{pst-barcode}

\newcommand{\sap}[2]{\centering
\begin{pspicture}(0,-0.2in)(2.8in,1.5in)\psbarcode[scaley=1.5]{#2}{includetext
 textsize=10 width=2.8}{code128}
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{labels}
\sap{Gblalbla1}{209ss4}

\sap{GGblalbla1}{20ss9214}

\sap{Gblalbla}{2092ss141}

\sap{blablabal}{209ss214}

\end{labels}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know what up to date TL 2015 means, but i just reinstalled MikTex 2.9, the newest version, chose XeLaTeX in the TexWorks Editor, and it doesn't work out of the box. I have to edit the config and the papersize.

Comment: i think the problem is also here described: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157216/xetex-pstricks-larger-page-size-is-cropped-to-a4